# Cargo feature flags still compile all default targets

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

I have a feature flag "my-flag" defined in the features section of the Cargo.toml file. I've applied the attribute `#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]` for conditional compilation at several places throughout my project-

1. To the mod declaration:

```
#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]
pub mod foo;
```

2. To entire files:

```
#![cfg(feature="my-flag")]
...
```

3. Targeted imports:

```
#[cfg(feature="my-flag")]
use foo::bar
```

4. Tests: sometimes the entire test file, other times individual tests

When I execute `cargo build` it compiles 1287 targets (libs, bins, etc.). When I execute `cargo build --features my-flag` it **still** compiled 1287 targets. It seems that the feature flags are not resulting in conditional compilation? I expect it to not compile **all** the modules (see point 1) & files (point 2).

I have a 2 questions:

1. Is there any other steps required for enabling conditional compilation with feature flags?
2. How can I be sure if the conditional compilation is working with the feature flags?

Comment: One comment: The things you marked with `#[cfg(feature="my-flag")]` are only compiled when you enable `my-flag`. So when it's enabled, you should expect it to compile more things, not fewer. And one question: How do you count "targets"? The cargo output of `Building [==> ] 465/1287`? That counts crates, but what you're enabling is a module. You can use [conditional dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies) to exclude entire packages from configuration, which would change that number.

Comment: "So when it's enabled, you should expect it to compile more things, not fewer" I know, I'm talking about that when it's disabled i.e. when I don't provide any feature flags. 
Yes I'm referring to the 1287 crates that you mentioned. It remains unchanged whether or not I pass the feature flags in cargo build. Is this expected?
@Caesar

Comment: @NewToCode If you don't have conditional dependencies, of course the number of crates compiled won't change.

Comment: Then what's the point of using conditional compilation with feature flags? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-features-section @ChayimFriedman

Comment: If it's still being compiled despite the #[cfg(feature="my-flag")]. Or does the cargo build show only `1287` crates & not the compiled info & these feature flagged files/modules are actually not being compiled? @ChayimFriedman

Comment: @NewToCode You can compile all crates, but still opt out for specific modules or statements or items.

Comment: How can I opt out of specific modules/files compilation? Isn't this handles by `#[cfg(feature="my-flag")]`? @ChayimFriedman

Comment: @NewToCode Yes, this is exactly what it does.

Comment: So why does the number of crates compiled doesn't change when I don't pass the `--features` flag? How can I check whether the conditional compilation of modules/files is working as expected? @ChayimFriedman

Comment: @NewToCode Try to call them and see if an error is raised. The number of crates doesn't change because you didn't feature-gated them.

Comment: Another [way to check](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1fb8951dcf60247f369f7c3f63819c62). And the point of this? Mostly, you combine it with [optional dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) and then use `#[cfg(feature = "dependency_name")]` to en/disable the part of your code that depends on the (now possibly disabled) dependency. What for? Your dependencies may take long to compile, or be hard to compile on some architectures, or you're a library author and want to keep your dependency tail thin.

Comment: What do you mean by "feature-gated them"? Is it the same as optional dependencies? @ChayimFriedman

Comment: I think we don't add the **dependency** name in the cfg attribute you wrote above. Rather we add the feature flag which have the optional dependencies defined for them as `my-feat = ["dep:a", "dep:b"]`. Or you're referring to something else? @Caesar

Comment: We're drifting away from the original question content, anyway: Certainly cleaner to do it your `my-feat` way (for example as a way to communicate to users of your crate which features are meaningful to specify manually), but cargo defines a feature of the same name for each optional dependency. So yes, it is possible to use `#[cfg(feature = "dependency_name")`.